# Needing to do some pattern matching with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a long string that a user entered. Using javascript I want to get the text of the first sentence IF it ends in a question mark. Is there a simple way I can do this?

For example:

```
var myText1 = "What is your name? My name is Michelle."
```

I need to return:     "What is your name"

```
var myText2 = "this is a test. this is a test."
```

I need to return:     "n/a"

Comment: Depends how reliable you want it to be. What constitutes a sentence for you?

Comment: Must be the first block of text that ends in a ". " or "? "     I don't need to do a very strong test so for example even the string "abc 1. and xx." would be a sentence "abc 1"

Comment: Then how would you handle *"Btw. what's your name?"*? (abbreviations in general)

Comment: I would handle it as "btw." which returns "n/a"

Comment: Or "How are you today Mr. Willoughsby?"

Comment: "How are you today Mr." which returns "n/a"

Answer (score 2):

Regex to the rescue:

```
var res = str.match(/^([^.]+)\?/);
var output = (res == null) ? 'n/a' : res[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused as to how practical this would be, but this should work.

```
var text = "this is a question? this is some text.";

var split1 = text.split(/[.?]+/); // splits the text at "." and "?"
var split2 = text.split(/[?]+/); // splits the text at "?"


// if the first element in both arrays is the same, the first sentence is a question.
var result = (split1[0] == split2[0]) ? split1[0] : "n/a";
```

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if text doesn't have either `.` and `?` (eg: if text was `"hello"`, result would be `"hello"`)

Comment: Absolutely, although the OPs definition of a sentence was "Must be the first block of text that ends in a . or ?". I personally think the whole premise is flawed and that a much more sophisticated approach is needed. But this works for what was asked.

Answer (score 0):

According to US English grammar rules, sentences end in `.`, `?` or `!`, but if the sentence ends in a quotation then a `"` will follow *(He said to me, "How are you doing?")*.  Does this count as a question?  The sentence itself is a statement quoting a question, so I'll assume the answer is no.  This makes it easier since we only have to account for `?` not followed by a `"`.

Given the above, here's my solution:

```
function startIsQuestion( str ) {
  var m = str.match(/^[^.!]+[?][^"]/);
  if (!m || 
      m[0].indexOf('.') >= 0 ||
      m[0].indexOf('!') >= 0 ||
      m[0].indexOf('?"') >= 0) return "n/a";
  return m[0];
}
```

I don't think it's completely robust, but I'm not sure of your complete requirements and it should give you a good start.

[**See demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8wRBA/1/)